Can I encode ID type as base64 with spring-graphql?
How can I encode the ID type as base64 in spring-graphql? note: I'm looking for a way to do it automatically for any field that the schema defines as ID, not writing this by hand in every controller that returns one.

If I understand correctly, you would like to parse/serialize String<->ID by base64 encoding/decoding values on the fly.
You can achieve custom parsing/serialization of values by using custom Scalars with graphql-java. Unfortunately, ID is meant to have a fixed, opaque representation and you cannot customize the coercing implementation of this base scalar type.
See the coercing implementation in graphql-java; this pretty much operators on .toString() and .valueOf() methods so I don't think there is much space there for this kind of behavior.
If this is a hard requirement of your application, creating a custom scalar is most likely the best solution here.

Wow, if you're not base 64 encoding it it's not all that opaque is it.… Oddly enough dgs does in fact allow this kind of coercion.... So I assumed spring graphql would as well. Like right now my api very obviously shows a uuid...

Interesting - can you point to a DGS docs page that describes this feature?
